# XSLT Row counter excluding Null and Zero

Tags: xslt

```
<Rows>
    <Row RowNo="1" Amount="0,0"/>
    <Row RowNo="2" Amount="12"/>
    <Row RowNo="3" Amount=""/>
    <Row RowNo="4" Amount="00"/>
    <Row RowNo="5" Amount="33"/>
    <Row RowNo="6" Amount="0,00"/>
    <Row RowNo="7" Amount="0"/>
    <Row RowNo="8" Amount="00,2"/>
</Rows>
```

These Row's are my input. I want the output to exclude rows where @Amount is '' or 0. And also not count the row for when @Amount = '' and = 0.
Expected result:

```
<Rows>
    <Row RowNo="1" Amount="12"/>
    <Row RowNo="2" Amount="33"/>
    <Row RowNo="3" Amount="00,2"/>
</Rows>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: To learn XSLT you should start by learning XPath as the expression language, then you at least know how to select the `Row` elements you want to output or, depending on your approach, those that you don't want to output. Counting/numbering items can be achieved in various ways, in general using `xsl:number`, in easy case by processing only the items you are interested in and then using `position()` to generate the number. So give that a try.

Comment: The only slight complication I see is your number format, if you have the comma `,` instead of the dot `.` as the decimal separator using the number type in XSLT/XPath for direct comparison is only possible if your input values are converted first or you rely on string comparisons.

Comment: The issue with position() here is that it gives me the position of the input. My attempts results in this:
`<Rows>
<Row RowNo="2" Amount="12"/>
<Row RowNo="5" Amount="33"/>
<Row RowNo="8" Amount="00,2"/>
</Rows>`

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show your attempt? Thank you!

Comment: You are supposed to show us your XSLT attempt so that we can then suggest ways to fix it, so consider to edit your question and show us your current code. If you use the right XPath like `Row[@Amount and not(number(translate(@Amount, ',', '.')) = 0)]` with `apply-templates` or  `for-each` to exclude the `Row` elements you don't want to output from the processing then `position()` should give you the right value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your given input, a **specific** (based on input) solution in **XSLT 1.0** can be as following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Rows>
        <xsl:for-each select="Rows/Row">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@Amount != '' and (number(@Amount) * 1) != '0' and translate(@Amount, '0', '') != ','">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:attribute name="RowNo">
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[@Amount != '' and (number(@Amount) * 1) != '0' and translate(@Amount, '0', '') != ',']) + 1" />
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                            <xsl:if test="name() != 'RowNo'">
                                <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"><xsl:value-of select="." /></xsl:attribute>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" />
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Rows>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks guys. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple, for a change?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Rows">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Row[translate(@Amount, ',0', '')]">
            <Row RowNo="{position()}" Amount="{@Amount}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```